# Iterate over an Array of Arrays in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I'm working with Handlebars for the first time. I have this complicated data structure that has an array with each item being an array of itself like:

```
rows: [[1a, 2a, 3a], [1b, 2b, 3b], [1c, 2c, 3c]]
```

I need to output in my html list items:

```
<ul>
 <li>1a</li>
 <li>1b</li>
 <li>1c</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff but nothing as worked so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Below you'll find a pure handlebar solution, the snippet can be run so you'll can test it by yourself. I've included 2 examples the first one is the solution you talked about, the second one include all rows. To have the first example working I had to define a "test" helper to evaluate the condition to only display the first occurence of each row in the subarrays.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var context = [['1a', '2a', '3a'], ['1b', '2b', '3b'], ['1c', '2c', '3c']];
  Handlebars.registerHelper('test', function(lvalue, operator, rvalue, options) {
    var doDisplay = false;
    var items = (""+rvalue).split("|");
    var arrayLength = items.length;
    for (var i = 0; (i < arrayLength); i++) {
      if (operator == "eq") {
          if (lvalue == items[i]) {
            doDisplay = true;
          }
        } else if (operator == "ne") {
          if (lvalue != items[i]) {
            doDisplay = true;
          }
        } else if (operator == "gt") {
          if (parseFloat(lvalue) > parseFloat(items[i])) {
            doDisplay = true;
          }
        } else if (operator == "lt") {
          if (parseFloat(lvalue) < parseFloat(items[i])) {
            doDisplay = true;
          }
        }else if (operator == "le") {
          if (parseFloat(lvalue) <= parseFloat(items[i])) {
            doDisplay = true;
          }
        }else if (operator == "ge") {
          if (parseFloat(lvalue) >= parseFloat(items[i])) {
            doDisplay = true;
          }
        }
    }
      if (doDisplay) {
        return options.fn(this);
      } else {
        return "";
      }
  });
 var source   = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html    = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
First row of each subarray : <br/>
<ul>
 {{# each this as |row|}}
  {{#each this as |subrow index|}}
  {{#test index 'eq' 0}}
  <li>{{subrow}}</li>
  {{/test}}
  {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>

Each rows of each array into 2 nested ul elements : <br/>
<ul>
 {{# each this as |row index1|}}
 <li>{{index1}}
 <ul>
  {{#each this as |subrow index2|}}
  <li>{{index2}} - {{subrow}}</li>
  {{/each}}
 </ul>
 </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is the snippet you can use in the handlebar. eq conditional check is coming from ember's truth helpers and for you can find similar package for your framework. This is assuming you always want to print second item of array,

```js
  {{# each rows as |row|}}
  {{#each row as |subrow index|}}
  {{#if (eq index 1)}}
  {{subrow}}
  {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
```